# Flutter Flame parallax not showing images on ios device

Tags: flutter, parallax, flame

here's my code and it works perfectly on Android, but doesn't show on ios devices, just black blank screen.

```
class MyParallaxComponent extends ParallaxComponent<RocketMan> {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    parallax = await gameRef.loadParallax([
      ParallaxImageData('rocket_bg/sky_color.png'),
      ParallaxImageData('rocket_bg/farground_cloud_1.png'),
      ParallaxImageData('rocket_bg/farground_cloud_2.png'),
      ParallaxImageData('rocket_bg/farground_mountains.png'),
      ParallaxImageData('rocket_bg/midground_mountains.png'),
      ParallaxImageData('rocket_bg/foreground_mountains.png'),
    ],
        baseVelocity: Vector2(5, 0),
        velocityMultiplierDelta: Vector2(1.8, 1.0),
        fill: LayerFill.width);
  }
```

and of course i add it in the game's onLoad():  add(MyParallaxComponent());.
It does show on the screen if I change the fill to LayerFill.height, but the images display huge and not as it's planned.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Impeller, if you turn off Impeller it will work.

You can try this with for example:

```dart
flutter run --no-enable-impeller
```

EDIT: This is fixed in Flutter 3.13